# How to solve this Coroutine circularly reference error?

Tags: typescript, types, coroutine

I have an exam tomorrow on coroutines, but the problem is that the lecture on that chapter was canceled for the exam and no replacement. So I decided to study coroutines on my own, which was hard.

I have example of code in TypeScript from the teachers, but the problem is that the example contains errors and I don't know how to solve them.

```
type Coroutine<s, e, a> = Fun<s, Either<NoRes<s, e, a>, Pair<a, s>>>
type NoRes<s, e, a> = Either<e, Continuation<s, e, a>>
type Continuation<s, e, a> = Pair<s, Coroutine<s, e, a>>
```

The errors I get is:

> Type alias 'Coroutine' circularly references itself
>
> Type alias 'NoRes' circularly references itself
>
> Type alias 'Continuation' circularly references itself

I understand why this happens, because `Coroutine` is of type `NoRes`, `NoRes` is of type `Continuation` and here we are back to beginning to complete the circle: `Continuation` is of type `Coroutine`.

What I don't understand is how to solve this and the alternative is how to implement a coroutine. So does anyone have a better and working example than the one above?

**Dependencies:**

Fun:

```
type Fun<a, b> = {
    f: (_: a) => b
    then: <c>(this: Fun<a, b>, g: Fun<b, c>) => Fun<a, c>
}
```

Either:

```
type Either<a, b> = {
    kind: "left"
    value: a
} | {
    kind: "right"
    value: b
}
```

Pair:

```
type Pair<a, b> = { First: a, Second: b }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same exam tomorrow and am also experiencing the error.

I managed to make it compile by creating an interface specially made for a Continued Coroutine like so:

```js
type Coroutine<s,e,a> = Fun<s, Either<NoRes<s,e,a>,Pair<a,s>>>
type NoRes<s,e,a> = Either<e,Continuation<s,e,a>>
type Continuation<s,e,a> = Pair<s,ContinuedCoroutine<s,e,a>>

interface ContinuedCoroutine<s,e,a> extends Coroutine<s,e,a> { }
```

Feels like a workaround but it will make unit compile too. I'm still trying to figure out join, map etc. however...

[This](https://github.com/giuseppemag/BCCC/blob/master/src/coroutine.ts) Might help you further. If you find a better way please update me ;)

Comment: Good luck on your exam